# Electron index.html not loading after building the app

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron app that works perfectly fine before bundling it with `electron-builder`. After bundling it and opening the app, I get the following error :

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///tmp/.mount_displa4VwuQh/resources/app.asar/file:/tmp/.mount_displa4VwuQh/resources/app.asar/build/index.html`

In the build folder I have the `electron.js` file and `index.html` and since the app is starting `electron.js` and thus `index.html` got bundled correctly.

Here is my `electron.js` app entry point(basically boilerplate):

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })


    // and load the index.html of the app.
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    win.on('closed', () => {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        win = null
    })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

When trying with `loadFile()` instead of `loadUrl()` I get the same error, but with this path instead : `file:///tmp/.mount_displa4VwuQh/resources/app.asar/index.html`

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like my problem was caused from improper packaging after all. Adding this in `package.json` "build" configuration fixed it:

```
"directories": {
  "buildResources": "build",
  "app": "build"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check once your directory path for index.html
I think you follow any tutorial and do not verify your path just once check I hope this will resolve your issue.

pathname: path.join(__dirname, `./src/index.html`),