# electron js - serving html

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to serve another `html` file so that browser can access it from `electronjs`. this is file directory:

```
app folder:
- index.js // this is the init file for electron.
- index.html // main interface.
- ip.js // <-- included in index.html, codes for serving the static html to browser.
- package.json
-- node_modules
-- pad: // <-- this is the root folder I want to access via browser
    - index.html // <-- browser will get to see this page.
    - pad_index.js
```

`index.js` will have basic `electron js` stuffs.
'index.html' will import and run `ip.js`, which contain codes to serve `./pad/index.html` to browser.

```
ip.js:
var os = require("os");

const http = require("http");
var path = require("path");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require("fs");

const port = 3000;

var staticBasePath = "./pad/";

var staticServe = function(req, res) {
  var resolvedBase = path.resolve(staticBasePath);
  var safeSuffix = path.normalize(req.url).replace(/^(\.\.[\/\\])+/, "");
  var fileLoc = path.join(resolvedBase, safeSuffix);

  var stream = fs.createReadStream(fileLoc);

  stream.on("error", function(error) {
    res.writeHead(404, "Not Found");
    res.write("404: File Not Found!");
    res.end();
  });
  res.statusCode = 200;
  stream.pipe(res);
};

var httpServer = http.createServer(staticServe);

httpServer.listen(port,  () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

When I test it with `electron .`, everything works. I can go to browser and type `http://localhost:3000/index.html` and it will show the content from `./pad/index.html`.

but after I use `electron builder` to build the app, then run the built app, I get `404: file not found!` in the browser. I am sure I missed out something very important but not sure what.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

According to electron builder configuration you have to change `directories` section to allow your files being packed together with the app.

Take a look in the `directories` section at: https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#configuration

This answer might be helpful
[Electron index.html not loading after building the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57832597/electron-index-html-not-loading-after-building-the-app)

Comment: thanks for the pointer, but I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. notice I have 2 `index.html`? those have different content in it. I can see `root/indext.html` fine, just that can't access to my `localhost:3000/index.html`, which is in `root/pad/index.html`.